# customizing google maps api to get a exclusive list of cities and towns across the globe in the dropdown instead of all the places available

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-markers

customizing google maps api to get a exclusive list of cities and towns across the globe in the dropdown instead of all the places available

Hi,
is there a way to fiddle with the googlemap api to place a constraint on the areas of interest that are available in the auto complete menu when we search.

i want my users to get the list of towns and cities and villages and points of interest but nothing else.
no stores, no business locations, no establishments

and i should be able to place my markers over those places and attach some photos to those markers..
can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only limit the results to either **geocode** or **establishments**.

You need to write your own autocomplete function using [**Place Searches**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches) (part of the Google Places API)

You can then limit your results to any type in [**THIS LIST**](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types).